# Checking duplicate data on multiple table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

We are making an approval system that is carried out in stages for companies. For that purpose, the requirement said that we need a template for grouping employee based on organization, location, job level, job title, and employment type so every employee with the same template has same step and layer of approvers.

Here's the high level [ERD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcbSy.png)

Here's my issue. Data from the organization, location, etc don't have just a few rows. Let say organization, location, and the other 3 entities have 50 row each, then I have to select from 50^5 rows to check an employee is having what template.

Not to mention I need to check a combination is not intersect with other templates so an employee must have no more than 1 template

#### Example:

I just use organization, joblevel, and jobtitle for this example

```
Employee A:
   Organization: BOD
   JobLevel: Manager
   JobTitle: General Manager

Employee B:
   Organization: ICT
   JobLevel: Senior
   JobTitle: Senior Web Developer
```

Let's say I have approval template
"Manager Approver" with member:

```
Organization: BOD
JobLevel: Manager
JobTitle: General Manager
```

This approval template means...all employees with specified organization BOD, jobLevel Manager, and jobTitle General Manager will have to use this template.

Another case, I want to make another approval template with member:

```
Organization: BOD, ICT (note we can use combination here)
JobLevel: Manager, Senior
JobTITLE: General Manager, Senior Web Developer
```

This template isn't valid because this will make Employee A have 2 eligible template

for checking this combination duplicate I have created a view

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW approval_template_members_view AS
    SELECT uuid() as id,
        at_organizations.organization_id AS organization_id,
        at_job_titles.job_title_id AS job_title_id,
        at_job_levels.job_level_id AS job_level_id,
        at.id AS approval_template_id
    FROM at
    INNER JOIN at_organizations ON at_organizations.approval_template_id = at.id
    INNER JOIN at_job_titles ON at_job_titles.approval_template_id = at.id
    INNER JOIN at_job_levels ON at_job_levels.approval_template_id = at.id;
```

For checking duplicate I just use Jpa Repository

```
@Query("SELECT COUNT(m) From approval_template_members_view m where m.organization.id IN ?1 AND m.jobTitle.id IN ?2 AND m.jobLevel.id IN ?3")
Long countByMember(List<String> organizationIds, List<String> jobTitleIds, List<String> jobLevelIds);
```

And check if this query result = 0 then it's safe / not duplicate with other.

I'm very aware that there will be a performance issue as time goes by, can someone recommend how to deal with this? Every suggestion will be very helpful

Comment: It might be just me, but I have no clue what you are trying to do. Could you add some sample data and the expected outcome? It will probably suffice if you just add only some types (e.g. organization and job title, I assume the rest behaves similarly?). Also, I don't see e.g. any e.g. employee data in your erd, if understand it correctly you want to find some (minimum) template (combination?) (verification?) that fits to an (all) employee(s), but for that, employee data is required. Please also show some query (even if it's not working) e g. "to check an employee is having what template".

Comment: @Solarflare sry for making you confused, this is my first time ask a question here so it may look so cluttered. I already provide some information for my question. Thanks!

Comment: It's no problem you confused me, and your edits cleared things up a lot, thanks. Specifically about that there are combinatorical templates (which is probably what I missed). I am still not sure where the steps come in (you didn't mention them in the update or your query), but I assume they are some kind of versioning system (which is probably not really relevant to your actual problem). If I understood your task correctly, this is basically just a join, but don't do that in your application. I'll add an anwer, feel free to correct me if I misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

We cannot verify your database model without knowing the requirements, so I am assuming it is correct. It looks suspicious though that you have an overlap in `level` and `title`, e.g. the combination `senior` and `junior developer` doesn't seem to make sense, yet you could insert it into your templates (or in other words: to make a template applicable to all `senior`-jobs, you would need to list them all in `titles` anyway, making the `level` redundant). This might just be an artifact of your sample data though and the actual title might be just `Web Developer`; but I would check that.

As you didn't mentioned it in your sample, I am ignoring the `steps`-table (which seems to be a versioning system), but you can probably include it by adding an additional `join` and maybe a `group by step`.

Your validation will indeed require a `join`, but you should let the database evaluate this, and not retrieve every combination using the view and check it yourself against all combinations. Optimizing `join`s and having methods to limit the size of intermediate resultsets (e.g. to *not* generate all 50^5 combinations to check if a specific one is in there) is a bread-and-butter-ability of a relational database system.

To verify that there is no duplicate entry in any of your templates, you can use

```
select l.location_id, jt.job_title_id, jl.job_level_id, 
   count(*) as dupcount, group_concat(jt.id) as duplicates
from template_job_titles jt 
join template_locations l on jt.id = l.id
join template_job_levels jl on jt.id = jl.id
group by l.location_id, jt.job_title_id, jl.job_level_id
having count(*) > 1;
```

The order in which you list the tables is not relevant, as the actual execution order is one of the things that MySQL will decide; you want to include your main `approval_template`-table (and the `steps`) though, I just skipped it for simplicity.

To check if a template that you want to add conflicts with any existing template (e.g. if you want to check if you can safely add the combinatorical template from your example that has two options for each table), use

```
select jt.id, l.location_id, jt.job_title_id, jl.job_level_id
from template_job_titles jt 
join template_locations l on jt.id = l.id
join template_job_levels jl on jt.id = jl.id
where (jt.job_title_id = 'General Manager' 
       or jt.job_title_id = 'Senior Web Developer')
  and (l.location_id = 'BOD' or l.location_id = 'ICT')
  and (jl.job_level_id = 'Senior' or jl.job_level_id = 'Manager');
```

This is much faster than the first query. If you never add conflicting templates (e.g. always check first, and use transactions), you would only need the second query.

Checking which user has which template is the same as asking if the template based on the user information is already in the table, so it's the same as the second query (without combinations of course); if you have doubts that there is only one template, add a `group by` or a warning.